# Error adding dynamic data to an existing site - 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. 'OrderBy' must be called before 'Skip'

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I am creating an ASP.NET web site which will support dynamic data. When I am creating a dynamic web site from scratch (from template in VS) all is working fine. But when I am trying to add dynamic entity (`.edmx`) file and running the application I am getting following error:

`The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.`

How do I prevent this error?

Comment: Hi Vinay. Please show us the code that is giving you that error

Comment: The whole code is auto genrated code, I dint even find "Skip" method anywhere in my code

Answer (score 0):

That error is actually very descriptive- it means exactly what it says.  Use the OrderBy extension method to sort the result set by any property and the Skip and Take extension methods will work.

```
var foo = from e in MyEntities.SomeEntity.OrderBy(x=>x.SomeProperty).Skip(100);
```

Comment: The Skip method must be in there somewhere... search your code for "Skip"

Comment: Which totally doesn't work if you don't know ahead of time what the incoming entity is.

Answer (score 0):

Okay...I got the answer, the problem was with the DynamicData folder it creaed, when we use LinqtoSQL with Dynamic data it creates different type of DynamicData folder and when we use LinqToEntity it creates another type of DynamicData folder..

Tahnks guys..